# Adding a PHP variable to HTML code

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a PHP variable, `$id`, which I previously retrieved in PHP code. This variable needs to be added to a string in HTML tags, like so:

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/" ID GOES HERE ></iframe>
```

However, I have no idea how to do this. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you made a basic research before asking ? This is the kind of stuff with bilions of results all over the world.

Comment: `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $id ?>"`

Comment: @YellowBird I tried to do what is contained in the answers I have been given but I put the PHP tags outside of the string and had no idea what I'd done wrong haha.

Comment: @DziNeIT - Generally, if you have tried something that didn't work it's a good idea to show what you have tried so people know you have put some effort into it first. Just provides some clarity really.

Comment: @webnoob Point taken - will do in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do assuming your page is a .php page.

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $id; ?>"></iframe>
```